# Delete photo in Gmail/Google profile without uploading another?

Tags: google-account-profile

I want to delete the photo associated with my Gmail account without adding another photo. I tried doing this in Google profile, but I could only find the option to upload a different photo (which I don't want to do). Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Gmail > Settings > General > My picture > Change Picture > Select No picture

Comment: Thanks! I got thrown off by the profile page that doesn't have this option. I'll accept your answer when it lets me.

Comment: Yeah, they are sneaky like that.

Comment: For me it changed the Gmail/chat pic but not the Google+ picture, so I used Noah's trick too.

Comment: I did this and I still have one when using GMail / Hangouts

Answer (score 8):

Look for and download a generic profile image and set it as your profile picture. No one will ever tell the difference.

Here's an example through Google Image search:

[image: generic profile placeholder image]

This is not my photo. I searched "default google profile photo" and clicked "Similar" on a photo then on another in those results and got it.

Depending on the size of the image you grab, it may result in the following error:

> The photo you uploaded is too small! It must be at least 250 pixels wide and 250 pixels tall.

Resize or find another image accordingly that would fit the dimension requirements.

Answer (score 4):

You can go into Picasa and delete the albums with the associated information you wish to delete. The above method doesn't actually remove your photo from the internet it just makes it harder to see. Trust no one.

Comment: I did all the other suggestions already, I even deleted my whole G+ and Profiles accounts and I only got rid of the stupid profile picture by deleting the Picasa "Profile Pictures" album entirely.

Comment: This is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Mail Settings dialogue. (Click the blue Gear Icon at the top right of the Gmail window, then click Mail Settings on the drop-down. If you still don't have a Gear icon, click the word Settings near the top right of the Gmail window.)

On the General tab, find My Picture. You can choose to enable either "Visible to everyone" or "Visible only to people I can chat with", or you can click Change Picture open a pop-up window, where you can choose to upload a different image or click No Picture to get rid of any image.