# Delete a profile photo from Google+ When Google+ Photos shows no record of the photo

Tags: google-plus

How do I delete my profile photo from Google+? I am having an incredible amount of trouble clicking through Google plus, trying to find the delete button.

**This situation is unique in the sense that only Google+ Picasa has access to the photo, rather than Google+ Photos**.

I think this must be a bug--I uploaded my profile photo straight to the profile from my computer, rather than selecting the photo from an album I'd uploaded to Google+.  As a result, only Google+ **Picasa** had access to the photo...Google+ "Photos" knew nothing about it--there was no record of my profile photo (even though it was obviously on the system)...and I could not delete the profile photo from my profile (since there was no delete option) or Google+ photos (since the application was not responsible for managing the photo).

Anywho...yeah, this is different from the other question...and **That is why I asked it!**

I guess the other question has Picasa deep down in the answers, and it isn't upvoted well, so now I'll be able to accept the proper answer (the **Picasa** answer), and associate that with this subject line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete photo in Gmail/Google profile without uploading another?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17687/delete-photo-in-gmail-google-profile-without-uploading-another)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that Google+ has several different photo applications--the "Photo" application and **Picasa**.  I don't know why, but only "Picasa" has access to your profile photo if the only way you added your profile photo was straight to the profile upload from your computer (rather than from an album already on Google+).

If you go to Picasa, then you can delete your profile photo.

Answer (score -1):

If you are facing trouble to delete the profile photo from Google+. I would say just go ahead and change with new photo as it is much simple and easy to do.

1. Go to Google Plus profile
2. Click on edit profile if you are using new Google Plus else click on profile picture if you are using older version of Google Plus
3. Change the picture with other

Comment: Information is right but this doesn't answer to the question.