# How do I delete very old photos from the "Insert Photo" dialog in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, privacy, photos

There was a time when it wasn't obvious to anyone that Google Hangouts was archiving all photos sent to and fro, into albums (much like Whatsapp). The Internet generally believed that Google wouldn't be so careless as to make private messages and pictures appear just anywhere unexpectedly.

Well, we weren't exactly wrong, but when you try to insert a photo in Gmail with this here...

[image]

...a dialog appears with photos from every Google-related source: Google Photos, Google+, **Hangouts**, etc.

I attempted to delete all traces of these photos by going through menus in Google Hangouts, Google+, Google Photos, and Google Drive, and I still can't seem to find where the older photos are stored.

How can I delete older photos that appear in the **Insert Photo** dialog of Gmail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Log into http://picasaweb.google.com and you should be able to find older photos that you don't find in Google Photos. Delete the pictures from there.

Source (someone else with the same problem):

- https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/Obo3xrS-Okk

---

I'm self-posting this question and answer despite the following thread...

- [Delete a profile photo from Google+ When Google+ Photos shows no record of the photo](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87920/delete-a-profile-photo-from-google-when-google-photos-shows-no-record-of-the-p)

...because there the question is about profile photos, which people may overlook if they're not concerned with profile photos. Also, that thread didn't appear in my Google search, so hopefully this reformulation does better with SEO.

Comment: Good question and good answer - perhaps you would like to mark it "accepted"?

Comment: Done, thanks for the reminder!

Comment: This will redirect you to a place now called *Google Album Archive* (which is the graveyard for all photos from closed down apps picasa, Hangouts, Blogger) and new ones like Drive. See https://support.google.com/picasa/answer/7008270

Answer (score 0):

Howdy I am trying to delete an image still showing on Gmail "insert photo" dialog. Said image was dated March 21, 2012.
I´ve tried finding that image within Picasa or Google Photos without success.
I have also tried "has:attachment" within Gmail and the same as above.
[image]

That´s the picture (March 21, 2012) I want to have deleted (had to block the image for privacy purposes though).

I´d appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 3

Log into http://picasaweb.google.com and you should be able to find older photos that you don't find in Google Photos. Delete the pictures from there.

Source (someone else with the same problem):

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/Obo3xrS-Okk  ------------------- I tried this but it did not work. Did not find said picture